# How to rapidly update android listview as data is loaded from network

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a normal listview/listadapter and I am loading a large amount of data from the network using an AsyncTask.  It takes around 5 seconds to completely download and parse all the data.

Rather than have the listview empty for 5 seconds while I am processing the data, I would like to update it as data is processed so the user can see and scroll through the list items as they are ready.  It takes around 20-50ms to process each item and have it ready for display.

Can someone please give me a hand with some ideas on how I can accomplish this.

I tried this code to only refresh every 500ms.  I call onNewItemReady() every 20 to 50ms from the AsyncTask when a new item has finished being processed:

```
public void onNewItemReady(Object item) {
    mData.add(item);

    long diff = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()-mLastRefresh;
    if (diff > 500) {
        mAdapter.setData(mData);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mLastRefresh = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    }
}
```

but if i scroll the listview before all the data has loaded, I receive the following error:

```
> 05-04 19:22:59.638: E/AndroidRuntime(24349):
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has
> changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the
> content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but
> only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls
> notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in
> ListView(16908298, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class
> MyAdapter)]
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**  I am not refreshing the adapter from the background thread. onNewItemReady() is being called from onProgressPublished from the AsyncTask.

Comment: Instead of `mAdapter.setData(mData);`, you might consider doing something like `mAdapter.addData(newItem);`

Comment: Besides, are you calling `onNewItemReady` from the UI thread or background thread?

Comment: Sorry to jump on you along with everyone else about using AsyncTask properly =) I'm not really sure why you're still getting the problem. What happens if you set your delay longer, say, 1000 ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an "endless adapter" and displaying an added "loading" view at the bottom of my listview when the user scrolled to the bottom.  I took the code that I was using from the Google i/o 2013 app.  Apparently this code was causing the problem.  I have since removed it and replaced it with a much simpler footerview and the problem has gone away.

this is the code I was using in my adapter:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (mData != null) {
         return mData.size() + (
              ((mDataTask.isLoading())        // we are already loading
             || mDataTask.hasMoreResults()    // or there are more results
             || mDataTask.isErrored())     // or there's an error
           ? 1 : 0);
        }
   return 0;
}
```

Instead of this code, I just add a footerview when i start loading, and i remove it when onPostExecute completes.

Answer (score 0):

As logcat message says you are trying to refresh the listview (which is on UI thread) from the background thread (probably AsyncTask ), so all you need to do is after the completion of execution of `doInbackground()` of the AsyncTask, you should refresh the listview in `onPostExecute()` of asynctask.

To avoid user interaction while your downloading process is going on, you should show a progress dialog in `onPreexcecute()`.

So your Asynctask should look like:

```
class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask{
ProgressDialog pd;
onPreExecute(){
 // show progress dialog here..
}

doInBackground(){
// perform network operation here and collect collect data
}

onPostExecute(){
// dismiss dialog box.
// refresh listview
}

}
```

Note this is just a blueprint for your code, for correct syntax refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

**Alternative**
Also as you are saying that you are loading large amount of data and it is taking almost 5 second ( this is lot of time ), it is a recommended to use `Pull-to-refresh`, as it will `load data on demand`. You can google it and lot of stuff is available there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I am using the proper asynctask workflow.  I dont want to display a progress dialog as I want the user to be able to scroll through the currently loaded items instead of waiting for all the data to be downloaded and processed.

Comment: Then you should look at `Lazy loading` in listview. That might help you.